# The correct word for adoption of a law by the National Assembly?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions

Since I am not a native English speaker I am not sure what word should I use for adoption of a law. The closest to my language is "adoption", but "promulgate", "enact" or some other word may be more appropriate.

Comment: It rather depends what you mean by "adoption" of a law. *Adopt* **is** used in some circumstances; and so is *promulgate* and *promulge* and *enact* and *bring into force*.

Comment: I mean, when some Draft-Law is accepted by the majority of votes by the representatives in Assembly and after that it is proclaimed in the Official Gazette and is “into force”.

Answer (score 1):

Different legislatures have different procedures, but *when some Draft-Law is accepted by the majority of votes by the representatives in Assembly and after that it is proclaimed in the Official Gazette and is “into force”* sounds rather like **enacting**.

In the UK, a law is *passed by both Houses* when it’s passed in Parliament but is only *enacted* when the Queen formally gives her assent to it. Even then it may have a later start date, which is when it is *brought into force*.

The UK *adopts* foreign legislation, for example when an EU directive is incorporated into UK law.

In the Church of England, canon law is *promulged* (not *promulgated*) when it’s passed by the General Synod. Again, it may *come into force* or *be brought into force* at a later date.